# ngAnimate working for show but not hide

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have an ngAnimate to slide a card in on show, and out on hide. Sliding in works, but sliding out has no animated effect.

html ...

```
<div  ng-hide="cardback.id == '{{n.id}}'" ng-show="cardback.id != '{{n.id}}'" ng-animate="{show: 'example-show', hide: 'example-hide'}">
```

and the css is

```
.example-show, .example-hide {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
  -o-transition:all linear 1s;
  transition:all linear 1s;
}

.example-show {
  top:-200px;
}
.example-show-active {
  top:0px;
}

.example-hide {
  top:0px
}
.example-hide-active {
  top:-200px;
}
```

I'm running 1.1.5 dated June 3rd

Comment: Remove the `{{` and `}}` from the expression and try.

Comment: if I remove the {{ }} then it simply doesn't trigger the event. The events are firing correctly, my problem is that the 'hide' event is instantaneous rather than animated

Comment: could you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co) demonstrating the problem. Chandermani really has a point regarding the double curlies. So I have my doubt about the events. Also the double hide/show is superfluous, this could also be a problem.

Comment: You need to add display:block!important to your `.example-show` and `.example-hide` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. The double-curlies really shouldn't be there. `ng-hide/show` values are already angular expressions, thus they are not needed. E.g. the following should be enough

   ```
   ng-hide="cardback.id == n.id"
   ```
2. Having `ng-hide/show` on the same element with exact oposite conditions seems strange. I guess, one would suffice.
3. You used `top` as transition property, though no `position` was defined. That could be a pasting mishap, but if not, you should also check on that.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/usaleq/5/) is a working example. Though without further input from your side it's just guesswork.

Comment: cracked it!
Chandermani was half right. I needed to remove the curlies **and** the single quotes, and I also removed the extraneous ng-show. 
Many thanks Ch & Yo